# Understanding decompiled Android method

Tags: java, android, decompiler, smali

I just got a task at my job to reverse engineer an application developed by a consultancy firm a year ago. They don’t have the source code, thats why I have to do this.

Anyways, there is a token that is converted from one string to another.

Example:

```
From:
H0zRNCGT4fnxPUaR0zuFO8HSWTZKYczetXf8vgfWgOAfZBwfE201MLgkbNu0lRuahspqLtrvMTMTivVxH6htYj+VGAbgJydH1OssYfW/RK4Acyxu1C/fCvlW1ccOePwzoboO9WLXj4781ahE+zQAVA==.

To:
H0zRNCGT4fnxPUaR0zuFO8HSWTZKYczetXf8vgfWgOAfZBwfE201MLgksNu0lRuahspqLtrvMTMTivVxH6htYj+VGAbgJydH1OsbYfW/RK4Acyxu1C/fCvlW1ccOePwzoboO9WLXj4781ahE+zQAVA==.
```

They do look the same but 2 chars have been replaced and I don't know for what reason.

Here is the difference made clearer by using spaces

```
From:
H0zRNCGT4fnxPUaR0zuFO8HSWTZKYczetXf8vgfWgOAfZBwfE201MLgk b Nu0lRuahspqLtrvMTMTivVxH6htYj+VGAbgJydH1Os s YfW/RK4Acyxu1C/fCvlW1ccOePwzoboO9WLXj4781ahE+zQAVA==.

To:
H0zRNCGT4fnxPUaR0zuFO8HSWTZKYczetXf8vgfWgOAfZBwfE201MLgk s Nu0lRuahspqLtrvMTMTivVxH6htYj+VGAbgJydH1Os b YfW/RK4Acyxu1C/fCvlW1ccOePwzoboO9WLXj4781ahE+zQAVA==.
```

I´ve used [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) as well as [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) to decompile the code

The java code from dex2jar does not make sense, well it gives you some clues but its not working code.

Here is the java code

```
private String b;

private String h()
    {
        int i = 56;
        int j = 0;
        String str;
        if (this.b == null)
            str = "";
        do
        {
            str = this.b;
        }
        while (str.length() <= 100);
        switch (str.charAt(71) % '\r')
        {
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 6:
        default:
            i = 0;
        case 1:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        }
        while (j != 0)
        {
            char c = str.charAt(j);
            return methodA(methodA(str, j, str.charAt(i)), i, c);
            j = 99;
            continue;
            j = 81;
            i = 50;
            continue;
            j = 45;
            i = 80;
            continue;
            j = 76;
        }
    }

    private static String methodA(String paramString, int paramInt, char paramChar)
    {
        StringBuffer localStringBuffer = new StringBuffer(paramString);
        localStringBuffer.setCharAt(paramInt, paramChar);
        return localStringBuffer.toString();
    }
```

And this is the smali code from the apktool

```
# instance fields
.field private b:Ljava/lang/String;


.method private h()Ljava/lang/String;
    .locals 5

    .prologue
    const/16 v1, 0x38

    const/4 v2, 0x0

    .line 138
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/example/MainActivity;->b:Ljava/lang/String;

    if-nez v0, :cond_1

    .line 139
    const-string v0, ""

    .line 185
    :cond_0
    :goto_0
    return-object v0

    .line 142
    :cond_1
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/example/MainActivity;->b:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 143
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->length()I

    move-result v3

    const/16 v4, 0x64

    if-le v3, v4, :cond_0

    .line 145
    const/16 v3, 0x47

    invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->charAt(I)C

    move-result v3

    rem-int/lit8 v3, v3, 0xd

    .line 150
    packed-switch v3, :pswitch_data_0

    :pswitch_0
    move v1, v2

    .line 170
    :goto_1
    if-eqz v2, :cond_0

    .line 177
    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Ljava/lang/String;->charAt(I)C

    move-result v3

    .line 178
    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/String;->charAt(I)C

    move-result v4

    .line 180
    invoke-static {v0, v2, v4}, Lcom/example/MainActivity;->methodA(Ljava/lang/String;IC)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 181
    invoke-static {v0, v1, v3}, Lcom/example/MainActivity;->methodA(Ljava/lang/String;IC)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    goto :goto_0

    .line 153
    :pswitch_1
    const/16 v2, 0x63

    .line 155
    goto :goto_1

    .line 158
    :pswitch_2
    const/16 v2, 0x51

    .line 159
    const/16 v1, 0x32

    .line 160
    goto :goto_1

    .line 163
    :pswitch_3
    const/16 v2, 0x2d

    .line 164
    const/16 v1, 0x50

    .line 165
    goto :goto_1

    .line 168
    :pswitch_4
    const/16 v2, 0x4c

    .line 169
    goto :goto_1

    .line 150
    nop

    :pswitch_data_0
    .packed-switch 0x1
        :pswitch_1
        :pswitch_0
        :pswitch_0
        :pswitch_0
        :pswitch_2
        :pswitch_0
        :pswitch_3
        :pswitch_4
    .end packed-switch
.end method



.method private static methodA(Ljava/lang/String;IC)Ljava/lang/String;
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 189
    new-instance v0, Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;

    invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 190
    invoke-virtual {v0, p1, p2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;->setCharAt(IC)V

    .line 191
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    return-object v0
.end method
```

If any one could figure out what is happening here I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: That looks like base64

Comment: been trying to decompile using base64 but it gives no usable information.

Comment: Which Java decompiler are you using on the converter jar?  Have you tried more than one?

Comment: I used dex2jar with JDGui, but I solved the problem anyway. I just walked trough the smali code and wrote the corresponding java code line by line. And it worked :)

Comment: In the future, you might try the Procyon decompiler.  It may handle some code better than JD-GUI, but it also tends to barf on converted Android code with nested exception handlers.